# How to check if every character of the string is different?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was just wondering, how to check if I ask a person to input a string, how do I check if every character inside that string is different?

For an example:

```
 string = str(input("Input a string: ")
```

I would like to do it with a while loop. So, if two characters in a string are different, it stays in the loop and prompts the user to input the string again.

Comment: Turn to set, compare size. BTW, what is the question? How to check the string, or how to ask again until the input is valid?

Comment: What is the "sign" in a string?  And do you want every sign different or no two signs different?  Or the same?

Comment: Doesn't comparing the size just compare how many signs there are in a string? I was thinking more like if there are two letters "a" in the string, it will stay in the loop

Comment: *So, if two signs in a string are different, it stays in the loop and prompts the user to input the string again.* Shouldn't that happen if two characters in the string are *the same*?

Comment: @strubbly , by sign i was thinking letters. i want all the letters to be different

Comment: Then do what @tobias_k says.  Try it yourself.  Take some strings and turn them into sets and see what happens.  Then you'll understand.

Comment: Do you also care about spaces duplicating or do you wanna ignore spaces?

Comment: spaces cannot duplicate either

Comment: In this case use Blcknght’s answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to reject any string that contains more than one copy of the same character. If a string with duplicated characters is entered, you want to repeat the prompt and get another input.

The easiest way to do the duplicate check is to create a `set` from your string and then check if the set has the same length as the original. If there were any duplicates in the string, they'll be present only once in the `set`.

```
while True:
    input_string = input("Enter a string")
    if len(set(input_string)) == len(input_string):
        break
    print("Please avoid repeating any characters")
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining this to me, i'm a noob in programming so I didn't really think i can work with sets like that.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try this:

```
while True:
    b = input("Enter a string: ") 
    if all([b[i] not in b[:i] + b[i+1:] for i in range(len(b))]):
        break
    print("Please try again!")
```

Comment: Admittedly, the first answer is probably better; people tend to frown upon complex and difficult-to-understand comprehensions that are programmatically less efficient.

Comment: `all(b.count(c) == 1 for c in b)` is probably a clearer way to do that. Either version will be O(N**2) though, so not a good idea for long sequences, but probably not too bad for the lengths of strings that are likely to be typed in an be unique.

Comment: Oh I couldn't remember the .count method, that's what I was looking for. But yah I knew it wasn't as good, I just thought it was more clear for small strings to understand what's happening.